# Kolmogorov distance properties

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are random variables. Does the following holds without assuming any further conditions:
$$
|\mathsf{P}(X+Z\le x)-\mathsf{P}(Y+Z\le x)|\le \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\mathsf{P}(X\le x)-\mathsf{P}(Y\le x)| \quad?
$$

---

It is easy to show that the inequality holds when $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$ because
$$
\mathsf{P}(X+Z\le x)-\mathsf{P}(Y+Z\le x)=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(X\le x-Z\mid Z)-\mathsf{P}(Y\le x-Z\mid Z)]
$$
and
$$
|\mathsf{P}(X\le x-z)-\mathsf{P}(Y\le x-z)|\le \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\mathsf{P}(X\le x)-\mathsf{P}(Y\le x)|.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no: take $X$ such that $-X$ and $X$ have the same distribution, $Y=-X$ and $Z=X$. For a negative $x$, $|\mathbb{P}(X+Z\le x)-\mathbb{P}(Y+Z\le x)|=\mathbb P(2X\leq x)$ while the right hand side of the wanted inequality is zero.